# TOPLEVEL_BINDING difference in irb and script

Tags: ruby

If i put the following code:

```
a = 42    
p TOPLEVEL_BINDING.local_variable_defined?(:a)
```

in a file "rubyScratch.rb" and ruby it using

```
ruby rubyScratch.rb
```

I get

```
true
```

However in irb I get

```
2.3.1 :001 > a = 42
=> 42 
2.3.1 :002 > TOPLEVEL_BINDING.local_variable_defined?(:a)
=> false
```

Why is there this difference?

Answer (score 8):

This is because the irb command (on my system, anyways) runs a small ruby script that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
#   irb.rb - interactive ruby
#       $Release Version: 0.9.6 $
#       $Revision: 40560 $
#       by Keiju ISHITSUKA(keiju@ruby-lang.org)
#

require "irb"

IRB.start(__FILE__)
```

So, the `TOPLEVEL_BINDING` is this script and not your IRB context.

While looking for some more information, I ran across [this short article](https://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/44-top-level-binding.html) which states:

> It is, as its name suggest, the Binding of your script's main scope:
>
> ```
> a = 42
> p binding.local_variable_defined?(:a) # => true
> p TOPLEVEL_BINDING.local_variable_defined?(:a) # => true
>
> def example_method
>   p binding.local_variable_defined?(:a) # => false
>   p TOPLEVEL_BINDING.local_variable_defined?(:a) # => true
> end
>
> example_method
> ```

To summarize, the `TOPLEVEL_BINDING` is the `binding` for the first script in the current context that was run by the Ruby VM.  When running IRB, that script is the one that starts the IRB session.